# Windows CE SQL Database connection error

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, winforms, windows-ce

I have a Motorola handheld scanner that is running windows CE 6.0, I developed a windows form app that runs off a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. The issue I am running into is establishing a database connection via the handheld device. When i test locally the connection establishes fine, but when running on the handheld it throws a SQLException error.

> *The SQL instance has named pipes enabled.*

Below is the test code to check if a connection establishes or not.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try
        Dim gDBConn As String = "Data Source=sqlserver;Initial Catalog=database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password"  

        Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(gDBConn)

        myConnection.Open()

        MsgBox("Established connection")

        myConnection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

- Enable TCP/IP for your database instance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909712(v=vs.90).aspx
- Change your connection string, by replacing "sqlserver" by the IP of your server

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly. I had the DNS name of the server in before, hard coding the IP in fixed the issue.